# Django Models Foreign Key get attributes

Tags: python, django

there are two classes in Models.py. First class creates the directory for the second class which upload image to that directory. The problem is that Image.image upload_to should take Image.directory.directory. Is there any solutions?

```
class Directory(models.Model):
    directory = models.CharField('Name of the folder', max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.directory


class Image(models.Model):
    directory = models.ForeignKey(Directory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='app/{}'.format(directory))
```

Thanks for your attention!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a *callable* to the [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
class Image(models.Model):
    def image_filename(self, filename):
        return f'app/{self.directory}/{filename}'
    
    directory = models.ForeignKey(Directory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_filename)
```